# How to create a link that rings a telephone number on a mobile?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Is it possible to create an image that when pressed (on a mobile), it rings the number? or puts the number into the handset ready to ring?

I'm sure I've seen something like this before on mobile websites.

Answer (score 3):

This HTML tag should do what you're looking to do:

```
<a href="tel:+1234567890">Call me!</a>
```